# want to compare date to update result auto after 48 hours but compare with date not working

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

```
$expiry = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' - 2 days'));

echo $expiry;

$data['booking_compeletation'] = 4;

$data['booking_status'] = 1;

$data['notification']=1;

$this->db->where(['booking_status'=>0,'booking_compeletation' => 1,'booking_check_out' > date('d-m-Y',strtotime(' - 2 days'))]);

$this->db->update('hotel_rooms_booking',$data);
```

Comment: change `'booking_check_out' > date('d-m-Y',strtotime(' - 2 days'))` to `'DATE(booking_check_out)' > $expiry`

Comment: any idea about it..?

Comment: I am just asking you to check it, i am not too much confirm about it.

Comment: i tried it but not working plz help

Comment: i think database column issu..? or any other to compare i dint know but not workingn in my case i have changed column to (date,datetime,varchar) and tried but in vain